# Webpack 4 splitChunks all + multi-configuration causes Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at ./webpack/bootstrap

Tags: webpack

Webpack 4 **splitChunks all** + **multi-configuration** causes

`Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at ./webpack/bootstrap`

[image]

If I turn off splitChunks, everything goes fine, but my app will increase tons of megabytes.

If I use single config + multi-entry mode, everything also goes fine, but I need two different alias

1. one has no alias
2. one has alias for react -> preact

Plus I want to splitChunks respectively, which is only possible in multi-configuration webpack mode.

Answer (score 0):

```js
module.exports = [
  {
    ...config1,
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      name: 'vendorsSmall',
    },
  },
  {
    ...config2,
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      name: 'vendors',
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should always explain **what** the problem is and **how** this code helps.

Comment: Actually, I don't know either, I figured it out randomly.